# Python Unexplained Invalid Literal Error (solution el alpha char at end of string)

Tags: python, python-3.4

So I've looked at the other SO questions and answers about this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

All of them were either because of an empty string, a string that represented a float, or a string that had extra quotes in it.

I'm getting this error for a string that should represent an integer.

I was wondering if anyone had an explanation of why this is happening?

input file:

```
1
10
123456789
3141592l
```

Here's my code:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
import sys, math

correct_set = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'}
test = open(sys.argv[1])
for n in test.readlines():
    result_set = set()
    i = 1
    while True:
        current = str(int(n) * i)
        done = False
        for char in current:
            if char not in result_set:
                result_set.add(char)
                if result_set == correct_set:
                    print(i)
                    done = True
                    break
        if done:
            break
        i += 1

print('time: {0} seconds'.format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Output:

```
10
9
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shane/PycharmProjects/acm-practice/magic multiple/magic.py", line 11, in     <module>
    current = str(int(n) * i)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3141592l'
```

If I add a print(repr(n)) in there I get:

```
'3141592l'
```

Which is expected.

I also tried dir(n) which gave the same result as previous iterations.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Oh.. I'm on windows 8 running python 3.4 in pycharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha character l (el) not 1 (one) is the last character in that string "3141592l" that you're trying to convert!
Also of interest, in your example readlines() will be appending a "\n" to each line.

Comment: I already tried that. :) You can tell that is not the issue based on the value that was printed by repr(n). Plus there is no newline at end of input file.

Comment: I upvoted your comment because it totally was PREVERSE LOL thanks.

Comment: See edit.  The character l (el) not 1 (one) is in that string "3141592l" that you're trying to convert.

Comment: Wow I didn't even see that!! Totally thought it was a 1.

Comment: Me too until I copy-pasted into my interpreter prompt and was like woah...  LOL